# MongoDB, does MaxPoolSize limit applies to all the client instances?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I increased `MaxPoolSize` value to 3000. does this mean that there are 3000 concurrent connections allowed using this instance, or it counts any other connections through other object instances too?

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://username:password@ip:27017/MyDB?maxPoolSize=3000"
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
return client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it's not exactly as you said. This [article](https://blog.mlab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/) provides a brief explaination of how connection pooling works is and it basically states that:

> Most MongoDB drivers support a parameter that sets the max number of
>   connections (pool size) available to your application. The connection
>   pool size can be thought of as the max number of concurrent requests
>   that your driver can service. The default pool size varies from driver
>   to driver, e.g. for Node it is 5, whereas for Python it is 100. If you
>   anticipate your application receiving many concurrent or long-running
>   requests, we recommend increasing your pool size- adjust accordingly!

The total incoming connection limit on the server is determined by the lesser of the limits imposed by the operating system or [maxIncomingConnections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.maxIncomingConnections) (or [maxConns](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/#maxConns) in MongoDB 2.4 and earlier).

Actually, the difference between the two settings is as follows:

- **Connection Pooling =** limit of connections per client
- **Connections Limit =** total allowed client connections

Comment: Thanks. I see the default `maxIncomingConnections` is `65536` on the server. But on the client side, it's sill not clear for me. for example in my code above, if I create a MongoClient object called `client` with 3000 max pool, and then create another object called `client2` with the same connection string, do I have 6000 connections?

Comment: No, this means that your server grants to each client no more than 3000 concurrent requests. And if you connect both clients to it, you will have 2 out of 65536 connections allocated.